# Automatically Control typesetting by item's ratio at page-break

Tags: lists, minipage, enumitem

**Qa**:

The choice-questions and options are defined through the list, but the layout is ugly due to automatic page change.

**Aim**:

I want to automatically correct the multiple choice questions and their options through the distribution ratio of the item at the broken page. The following is the effect of wanting to automatically repair the questions in `MWE`：

1. The layout of the (1) question is acceptable.
2. The layout of the (2) question isn't acceptable.The widow line should be bottom of 3 page.（Solved by variable `\baselineskip`）

```
\baselineskip=1\baselineskip plus 0pt minus 5pt \relax
```

3. The layout of the (3) question isn't acceptable. The choice-question body should be top of 6 page.(unsolved)
4. The layout of the (4) question isn't acceptable. The choice-question body should be top of 8 page.(unsolved)

**Idea**:

Put the question-body and question-options into the **minipage**, turn off the automatic paging of the minipage and define a patch for the **minipage** to change the page by the number of items. Don't know if this idea is feasible, if not, is there any other solution?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\textheight10.5\baselineskip
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ExampleQuestionEnumerate, 1]{
    fullwidth,
    labelindent=0pt,
    label=(\arabic*),
    labelwidth=!,
    labelsep = 0pt,
    leftmargin=!,
    topsep=0pt plus 2pt,
    partopsep=0pt plus 1pt,
    parsep=0pt,
    itemsep=2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt,
    resume
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\choiceQuestionBody}{ +m } {
        \item #1
}

\newlist{PerLineOptions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[PerLineOptions, 1]{
    label=\Alph*.,
    labelsep=0.5em,
    leftmargin=*,
    align=left,
    widest=D,
    nosep
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fourOptionsInFourLines}{+m +m +m +m}{
    \begingroup
        \begin{PerLineOptions}
            \item #1
            \item #2
            \item #3
            \item #4
        \end{PerLineOptions}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}[start=1]
        \choiceQuestionBody{\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1][1]}
        \fourOptionsInFourLines 
        {option a}
        {option b}
        {option c}
        {option d}
    \end{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}
    \newpage
    
    \begin{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}[start=2]
        \choiceQuestionBody{\lipsum[2]}
        \fourOptionsInFourLines 
        {option a}
        {option b}
        {option c}
        {option d}
    \end{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}
    \newpage
    
    \begin{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}[start=3]
        \choiceQuestionBody{\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1][1-4]}
        \fourOptionsInFourLines 
        {option a}
        {option b}
        {option c}
        {option d}
    \end{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}

    \newpage
    \begin{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}[start=4]
        \choiceQuestionBody{\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1][1-2]}
        \fourOptionsInFourLines 
        {option a}
        {option b}
        {option c}
        {option d}
    \end{ExampleQuestionEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see how you would ever get acceptable output from `\baselineskip=1\baselineskip plus 0pt minus 5pt \relax`  It is not clear what problem you are solving but that can not be the solution, it is like curing a headache using  a guillotine.

Comment: Currently you get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5IDM.png) I do not understand your requested layout for 3 and 4 there is not room for question and choices. Why not simply always ban a page break between the choices, but allow a page break after the question before the list of choices?